# Lag operator computations

Tags: recurrence-relations

given $$h_t=\alpha_0+(1-\beta_1)\epsilon^2_{t-1}+\beta_1Lh_t$$ where $$Lh_t=h_{t-1}$$ how can I obtain $$h_t=\alpha_0/(1-\beta_1)+(1-\beta_1)\sum_{1=0}^\inf\beta_1^i\epsilon^2_{t-1-i}$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

\begin{eqnarray}
h_t &=& \alpha_0 + (1 - \beta_1)\epsilon_{t - 1}^2 + \beta_1 \color{blue}{h_{t - 1}} \\
&=& \alpha_0 + (1 - \beta_1)\epsilon_{t - 1}^2 + \beta_1 \left[\color{blue}{\alpha_0 + (1 - \beta_1)\epsilon_{t - 2}^2 + \beta_1 h_{t - 2}}\right] \\
&=& \alpha_0 (1 + \beta_1) + (1 - \beta_1)[\epsilon_{t - 1}^2 + \beta_1 \epsilon_{t - 2}^2] + \beta_1^2 \color{red}{h_{t-2}} \\
&=& \alpha_0 (1 + \beta_1) + (1 - \beta_1)[\epsilon_{t - 1}^2 + \beta_1 \epsilon_{t - 2}^2] + \beta_1^2 \left[\color{red}{\alpha_0 + (1 - \beta_1)\epsilon_{t - 3}^2 + \beta_1 h_{t - 3}}\right] \\
&=& \alpha_0 (1 + \beta_1 + \beta_1^2) + (1 - \beta_1) [\epsilon_{t - 1}^2 + \beta_1 \epsilon_{t - 2}^2 + \beta_1^2 \epsilon_{t - 3}^2] + \beta_1^2 h_{t - 3}
\end{eqnarray}

you can add a few more terms, but it is already fairly straightforward to see the pattern. If you consider $n$-lags you will get

$$
h_t = \alpha_0 \sum_{k=0}^n \beta_1^k + (1 - \beta_1)\sum_{k = 0}^n \beta_1^k \epsilon_{t - k - 1}^2  + \beta_1^n h_{t - n} \tag{1}
$$

And now it is a matter of taking the limit $n\to\infty$. If $|\beta_1| < 1$ then the first term in Eqn. (1) is just a convergent [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and the last term goes to zero, so you end up with

$$
h_t = \frac{\alpha_0}{1  - \beta_1} + (1 - \beta_1)\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \beta_1^k \epsilon_{t - k - 1}^2
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the second summation in Eqn. (1) start from $k=0$?

Comment: @Fabio Yup, those are just typos, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions. Call:

$\begin{align*}
  H(z)
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} h_n z^n \\
  E(z)
    &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \epsilon^2_n z^n
\end{align*}$

Write your recurrence as:

$\begin{align*}
   h_{t + 1}
     &= a_0 + (1 - \beta_1) \epsilon^2_t + \beta_1 h_t
\end{align*}$

Multiply by $z^t$, sum over $t \ge 0$, recognize the resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{t \ge 0} h_{t + 1} z^t
    &= a_0 \sum_{t \ge 0} z^t
         + (1 - \beta_1) \sum_{t \ge 0} \epsilon^2_t z^t
         + \beta_1 \sum_{t \ge 0} h_t \\
  \frac{H(z) - h_0}{z}
    &= a_0 \frac{1}{1 - z}
         + (1 - \beta_1) E(z)
         + \beta_1 H(z)
\end{align*}$

Solve for $H(z)$, split into partial fractions:

$\begin{align*}
  H(z)
    &= \frac{h_0 + (a_0 - h_0 + E(z) (1 - \beta_1)) z - E(z) (1 - \beta_1) z^2}
            {1 - (\beta_1 + 1) z + \beta_1 z^2} \\
    &= - \frac{E(z) (1 - \beta_1)}{\beta_1}
           + \frac{a_0 }{1 -  \beta_1} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z}
           + \frac{E(z) -  \beta_1 (a_0 + 2 E(z)) + E(z) \beta_1^2 + \beta_1 (1 - \beta_1)}
                  {\beta_1 (1 - \beta_1) (1 - \beta_1 z)}
\end{align*}$

We want the coefficient of $z^n$ in this, written $[z^n]$. This is a handful. but the pieces are easy to handle:

$\begin{align*}
   [z^n] E(z)
     &= \epsilon^2_n \\
   [z^n] \frac{1}{1 - \beta_1 z}
     &= \beta_1^n \\
   [z^n] \frac{E(z)}{1 - \beta_1 z}
     &= \sum_{0 \le t \le n} \epsilon^2_t \beta_1^{n - t} \\
   [z^n] \frac{1}{1 - z}
     &= 1
\end{align*}$

The rest is a bit of messy algebra.